# Python PYMC3 matrix multiplication

Tags: python, pymc3

I have started to learn PYMC3. i am trying to write a simple matrix multiplication using PYMC3. basically would like to learn and understand how the arithmetic operations can be done in PYMC3.

Below is my code,

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm 


dimension_N = 3
min = 0
max = 100

Matrix_A = np.random.randint(min,max,(dimension_N,dimension_N)).astype(np.uint8)
Matrix_B = np.random.randint(min,max,(dimension_N,dimension_N)).astype(np.uint8)
Matrix_C = np.zeros((dimension_N,dimension_N))

with pm.Model() as model:
    c = pm.Normal("c", mu=0, sigma=1)
    a = pm.Normal("a", mu=0, sigma=1, observed=Matrix_A)
    b = pm.Normal("b", mu=0, sigma=1, observed=Matrix_B)
    c = a.dot(b)

    gph = pm.fit()
```

Not sure if this is the correct code.  Can you please help me ? from my observation variable c returns 0.  Can you please tell me what went wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside that the model here is not clear, we can still answer how matrix multiplication should be done when working with PyMC3 `RandomVariable` objects. Namely, RV's in PyMC3 are [`theano.tensor.TensorVaribale` objects](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/tensor/basic.html#tensorvariable), and therefore, should use the `theano.tensor.dot` method to matrix multiply them. E.g.,

```
import theano.tensor as tt

tt.dot(a,b)
```

Generally, consult [the Theano Tensor Functionality documentation](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/tensor/basic.html) for API to do efficient math with PyMC3.